# Boolean radio-buttons in Angular 2+ Forms

Tags: forms, angular

I want to be able to have a radio button group of two items in order to have a yes-no toggle.

The following snippet works, but has a "true"/"false" **string** value as item.value

```
<input type="radio" [formControl]="item" name="{{item.id}}" value=true>
<input type="radio" [formControl]="item" name="{{item.id}}" value=false>
```

How do I get an **boolean** value in item.value?

I tried the following without success:

```
<input type="radio" [formControl]="item" name="{{item.id}}" [ngValue]=true>
<input type="radio" [formControl]="item" name="{{item.id}}" [ngValue]=false>
```

It throws

```
Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known native property
```

I am using Angular 2 RC4 with Angular Forms 0.2.0.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```html
<input type="radio" [formControl]="item" name="{{item.id}}" [value]=true>
<input type="radio" [formControl]="item" name="{{item.id}}" [value]=false>
```